# concatenation of two measures in mdx query result

Tags: mdx, olap

is it possible to concatenate two measures values into one cell ?

this is the sample query but it doesnt work:

```
    WITH member [Measures].[tmp] as ([Measures].[m1] + " " + [Measures].[m2])
SELECT {[Brand].[Brand Name].[Brand Name]} ON ROWS, {[Measures].[tmp]} ON COLUMNS FROM [DEVEL]
```

thank You very much for any help

Comment: What do you mean by 'it doesnt work'? Do you get an error message? Which result were you expecting? Which result do you get?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you need to make it clear you are after the `.Value` of the member, otherwise the MDX parser thinks you mean the member (object) itself?

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[tmp] AS '[Measures].[m1].Value & " " & [Measures].[m2].Value'
```

I've also tweaked the syntax a bit: I think you need `&` to concatenate (like VBA, which MDX understands if using MS OLAP), and you should need single quotes around the definition after the `AS`.

Alternatively, if you are using your own code to call MDX, then you can read the cell values yourself, and concatenate anything you want before displaying it?